# In MacOS, is it possible to programatically control the screen magnification feature provided by accessibility options

Tags: macos, api, accessibility

I'm visually impaired and I use Mac OS screen magnification all the time. 
It works well.

I scroll the mouse wheel while holding the control key to zoom in and out.
I can see any region of the magnified screen by moving the mouse.

Is there an API to programatically control these features?

I'd like to be able to automate some gestures, similarly to IDE macros.

For instance, I'd like automatically adjust zoom and focus to new dialog boxes as they show up on screen.

If there isn't an API to directly control magnification, would it be possible to simulate the keystrokes and mouse gestures that activate the zoom features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/) from the Mac os x developer library that describes the concept of "Accessibility Programming" where you would be able to find what you need. It covers the aspect of programming in order for the clients to have a special "accessibility" to your applications.

> The accessibility API provides protocols that define how accessibility
>   clients interact with your app

You should start from here before trying to implement the magnification control.